# Dual boot Windows 8 x2 with truecrypt

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, partitioning, truecrypt, disk-encryption

For now i have that configuration:

- SSD - partition C - Windows 8 (unencrypted)
- RAID0 (2x500GB HDD) partition D - Data - encrypted with TrueCrypt.

I want to make something like that:

- SSD - partition C - Windows 8 - encrypted with TrueCrypt
- RAID0 (2x500GB HDD):
- - Partition D - Data 900GB - encrypted with TrueCrypt
- - Partition E - Windows 8 - unencrypted

And scenario of booting looks like that:

```
                     Windows 8 - partiton C -> TrueCrypt prompt for for password -> Boot and start system -> Mount partition D in TrueCrypt

Prompt to 
choose operating -> 
system 

                     Windows 8 - partition E -> Boot and start system
```

And my questions:

1. It's possible to do? If yes, what i should do to achive this?
2. How about compatibility? Windows 8 has this fast boot option. Does it reduce the security of my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to first remove the HDD RAID, install Windows 8 on your SSD and encrypt with TrueCrypt.

Remove the SSD and install the HDD RAID. Partition the drive for 100GB for your second Windows 8 installation. Leave the 900GB alone. Once installed, install TrueCrypt.

Plug the SSD back in.

You can then press `F8` (or whatever your hotkey is to select the bootable drive).

Once you log into either Windows, you can launch TruCrypt and select your 900GB partition to encrypt. It is useful to note that if you make the 900GB's passphrase the same as your SSD's passphrase, then you can enable automatic mounting of this drive. However, you would need to manually mount the drive in your HDD RAID upon each boot.

I wouldn't worry about the Fast Boot so much as hibernation/sleep (if they aren't the same thing. honestly not sure). Hibernating your computer or putting it to sleep can leave you open for attack if someone had physical access to your computer.

Comment: Today I changed boot settings. Finally I only had to press escape on pre-boot authentication to load unencrypted OS but when I type password my encrypted OS from SSD is booting.

Comment: If you're at the passphrase screen of TrueCrypt on boot, then you have already passed the boot selection menu and the default drive is being booted from.